# 2 sidebarpanel in Navbarpage in the same tab

Tags: html, css, shiny

This is a navbarpage in Shiny. Can I add 2 sidebarpanel with space in middle as shown in below diagram. Can we add html tags to create this spacing?

[image]

Below is the code for it (Basically I need a gap between tickers)

ui.R

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram

navbarPage("Trading",
           selected = "Data",
           tags$script(src = "app.js"),
           tags$style("body {background-color: skyblue;}"),
           tabPanel("Data",
                    sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(selectInput('ticker','Ticker',choices = c("",levels(factor(Ticker$Ticker))),selected = ""),
                                   # uiOutput("measures"),
                                   # uiOutput("interval"),
                                   # uiOutput("click_button"),
                                   selectInput('ticker1','Ticker',choices = c("",levels(factor(Ticker$Ticker))),selected = ""),
                      width = 2),
                      mainPanel(dataTableOutput("display"))
                    )))
```

Comment: how much space do you need

Comment: May be for now it’s random. I use br(). But it won’t create blue gap as shown. Rather it extends that I don’t need

Comment: Wanted to check if u need any info

Comment: tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.space-bottom {margin-bottom: 80px;}'))) is it work

Comment: space-bottom is a class right? Where should I declare it?

Comment: in upper sidebarpanel

Comment: I have added my code in my UI. Can you please try

Answer (score 0):

```
navbarPage("Trading",
           selected = "Data",
           tags$script(src = "app.js"),
           tags$style("body {background-color: skyblue;}
                       #pb_100 {padding-bottom: 100px;}"),
           tabPanel("Data",
                    sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(tags$div(id="pb_100", style='margin-bottom: 100px',
     selectInput('ticker','Ticker',choices = c("",levels(factor(Ticker$Ticker))),selected = "")),
                                   # uiOutput("measures"),
                                   # uiOutput("interval"),
                                   # uiOutput("click_button"),
                                   selectInput('ticker1','Ticker',choices = c("",levels(factor(Ticker$Ticker))),selected = ""),
                      width = 2),
                      mainPanel(dataTableOutput("display"))
                    )))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but still the same. :( Not getting a gap between

Comment: Nope got error "ERROR: unused argument (style = "margin-bottom: 80px;")"

Comment: Nope man :) It is still the same. There is no gap created between 2 filters. Please refer the diagram in my question